# Laying out objects on the stage in code?

Tags: actionscript-3, indexing, flash-cs5

When I'm laying out objects on the code, I noticed that I'm having a hard time getting things to stack properly. I know that I need to be dealing with the `index` property, but I don't know how.

What are some properties, methods etc that can help me easily move around my objects on the stage and visually stack them properly? (Also, can multiple objects have the same index?)

Example:

> Index 5 - Button 2
>
> Index 4 - Button 1
>
> Index 3 - Header MC
>
> Index 2 - Footer MC
>
> Index 1 - Content Area MC
>
> Index 0 - Background

Comment: i think you need to clarify what you mean by "stack"

Comment: @grapefrukt - I mean the z-index. tacking objects on top of each other. (Edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you add children to the stage you can use the addChildAt(displayObject,index) method. You can specify what index to add the new child at. Everything in the display list at and above the index you specify will be shifted up.

You can move an objects in the display list with setChildIndex(displayObject,int), where int is the index to move the object to.

Lastly, you can get the index of a display object with getChildIndex(displayObject). This will return the index and you can combine this method with the above two to get all of your objects sorted properly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The int you specify for the layer must be within the range of the existing number of objects in the list. (i.e., if there are 10 objects in list, and you try to add something at index 11, you will get that out of range error).

Comment: Another way to think of this is that the list can not have any empty positions. Every index from 0 to the total number of children must have a child at that index.